# React hook for Facebook Comment - preload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook, react-hooks

How to pre-load an iframe with React hook.

Recently i implemented a Facebook Comment Tool on my page. https://jackylenghia.com/#/Contact

However, look like iframe requires a preload (i.e. in `ComponentDidMount` in old React), so the iframe does not appear, but you will need to refresh the page (F5 or Cmd + R), to let the iframe loaded.

How should I fix this with React Hook.
I tried to by loading this with useEffect but does not help

Original:

```
const Contact = (props) => {
  return( 
     ... //Other stuffs

     <Col>
       <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://jackylenghia.com/#/Contact" data-numposts="5" data-width=""></div>
     </Col>
     ...
  )
}
```

What I tried

```
const Contact = (props) => {
  const [fbcomment, setfbcomment] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setfbcomment(`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://jackylenghia.com/#/Contact" data-numposts="5" data-width=""></div>`);
  });

  return( 
     ... //Other stuffs

     <Col>
       {fbcomment}
     </Col>
     ...
  )
}
```

But this only print out a text string only, instead of inserting the element to dom

Comment: Your're storing a string in the state. What you're trying to do is store the component, **but you shouldn't be storing a component in state either**. State is for storing _data_, such as strings, objects, numbers, etc. I think you're also getting confused about the order of execution. The useEffect runs AFTER the render cycle, so in the original example, the FB comment gets rendered before any useEffect runs. In the second example, your render cycle runs twice, first with `fbComment` as `0` and again after you set it to a string.

Comment: @JMadelaine isn't `useEffect` with be replaced for `ComponentDidMount` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). If not, where should be the better place to load this iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out, to preload the iframe, I only need to run this from FB JavaScript SDK, in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect (() => {
  FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

This will request FB component to be parsed after dom loaded.